# When dtype is specified with genfromtxt a 2D array becomes 1D - how to prevent this?

Tags: python, numpy

As seen here:

http://library.isr.ist.utl.pt/docs/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html#choosing-the-data-type

> "In all the cases but the first one, the output will be a 1D array with a structured dtype. This dtype has as many fields as items in the sequence. The field names are defined with the  names keyword."

The problem is how do I get around this? I want to use genfromtxt with a data file with columns that are, e.g. int, string, int.

If I do:

```
dtype=(int, "|S5|", int)
```

Then the entire shape changes from (x, y) to merely (x, ) and I get 'too many indices' errors when I try to use masks.

When I use dtype=None I get to keep the 2D structure, but it often makes mistakes if the 1st row the  column looks like it could be a number (this often occurs in my data set).

How am I best to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a 2D array, it would mean having 1D arrays with mixed dtype for each row, which is not possible.

Having an array of records shouldn't be a problem:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: !cat test.txt
42 foo 41
40 bar 39

In [3]: data = np.genfromtxt('test.txt',
    ..:     dtype=np.dtype([('f1', int), ('f2', np.str_, 5), ('f3', int)]))

In [4]: data
Out[4]:
array([(42, 'foo', 41), (40, 'bar', 39)],
      dtype=[('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<U5'), ('f3', '<i8')])

In [5]: data['f3']
Out[5]: array([41, 39])

In [6]: data['f3'][1]
Out[6]: 39
```

If you need a masked array, look here: [How can I mask elements of a record array in Numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7217606/1258041)

To mask by 1st column value:

```
In [7]: data['f1'] == 40
Out[7]: array([False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [8]: data[data['f1'] == 40]
Out[8]:
array([(40, 'bar', 39)],
      dtype=[('f1', '<i8'), ('f2', '<U5'), ('f3', '<i8')])
```

Comment: I see, that's an interesting approach, thank you. Is it possible to use masks in a similar way with this set up? With 2 dimensional arrays I did something like mask_column1 = data[:,0] == 'some value'; print(data[mask_column1]) - of course this now gives an error.

Comment: @James If I understand what you mean, the edit should show an example